# Using user's input as a host in a Python-based primitive "browser"

Tags: python

I have a trivial question. How can I use user's input as an URL in a Python app with socket libraries?

I have this code:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

And now I'm supposed to change it so that the app opens an URL provided by the user, not the one which is now hard-coded. I've tried many things, all of 'em fail with a different error message.

The things I tried:
1)

```
url = input("Enter URL: ")
[...]
cmd = 'GET url HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)
```

2. 

Then I tried separating my url variable from the rest of the line with commas:

```
cmd = 'GET', url, 'HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
```

3. 

I also tried to be creative:

```
url = input("Enter URL: ")
realurl = "GET" + " " + url + " " + "HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()"
[...]
cmd = realurl
mysock.send(cmd)
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's now skip the problem with mysock.connect's content - I was trying to launch the app with a link to page on the same host.

Comment: What "many" things have you tried?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter
I answered your question by editing my first post.

Answer (score 1):

`cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()`

should be

`cmd = 'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()`

domain shouldnt be included in the path...add a `host` header which has `http://data.pr4e.org/` as the value....

Answer (score 1):

If you had printed the `cmd` then your issue would be rather clear. Formatting was incorrect and `.encode()`needs to be applied to the entire concatenated string!

1. `cmd = 'GET url HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()` is a bytes like obj that doesn't include the actual url
2. `cmd = 'GET', url, 'HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()` is a tuple `(str, str, bytes)`
3. `realurl = "GET" + " " + url + " " + "HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()"` is a string that contains a string `.encode()` rather than applying it to the `str`.

```
url = input("Enter Url: ")`
cmd = 'GET ' + url + ' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
# Encode encodes a string to a bites like obj.
# Therefore we must apply it to the entire string!
mysock.send(cmd.encode())
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent clarification. You're right, I should have thought about printing cmd. It's been a valuable lesson. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped!